# 401 error - IIS7.5 site does not fall back from Kerberos to NTLM

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, kerberos, ntlm

I have a site hosted in IIS7.5 on Win2008 R2.

Assume the server is called 'prod1' and the site is bound to a hostname of MySite, and also to prod1:8080. The site's application pool runs in a domain account: domain\IISuser.

SPNs have been created:

- HTTP/MySite domain\IISUser
- HTTP/MySite.mycompany.com domain\IISUser

IISUser has been configured for unconstrained delegation.

The site's web.config contains the following:

```
<windowsAuthentication 
    enabled="true" 
    authPersistNonNTLM="true" 
    useKernelMode="true" 
    useAppPoolCredentials="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
    <add value="Negotiate" />
        <add value="NTLM" />
    </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

Browsing (with my corporate user account) to `http://MySite` works, and NetMon shows that Kerberos auth succeeds.

The issue is that I hoped it would also be possible to browse to `http://prod1:8080`, with authentication falling back to NTLM if needed, but I'm getting a 401 error and repeated login prompts (in IE11) instead.

In the latter scenario, NetMon shows that the server's first response is (as expected) 401, and contains `WWWAuthenticate: Negotiate` and `WWWAuthenticate: NTLM` headers.

The browser makes a new request with an `Authorization: Negotiate` header and SPN of `HTTP/prod1.mycompany.com`. No such SPN exists, and the server response is 401 - KRB_ERROR - KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED, along with a `WWWAuthenticate: Negotiate` header (no NTLM one this time).

At this point I'd hope the browser would make an NTLM request, but instead it makes another Negotiate request, identical to the previous one, with the same result.

Is the scenario I'm attempting to support possible - if so where am I going wrong with the configuration?